# Is there any version of Botanicula compatible with Yosemite?

Tags: macos, backwards-compatibility, botanicula

I have a `.dmg` file of the game Botanicula (version 1.0.0) on my Mac.

When I open it a warning tells me "image not recognized." Is that related to compatibility or from another problem?

Comment: Should I ask this question at apple.stackexchange.com?

Comment: I'm not familiar with [apple.se], but you might get better help there. Your question is still on topic here since it's about a game, but most PC gamers here are Windows user, so most of us here won't be able to help you, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sounds like it has nothing to do with Botanicula itself and everything to do with the `.dmg` file, since it sounds like an error you'd get while trying to mount the `.dmg` (double-clicking it) and *not* trying to launch the application itself.

It looks like the game itself is at version 1.1, so your version isn't so old that the `.dmg` would be in some legacy, unsupported form. What is more likely is that your `.dmg` is simply corrupt, possibly due to a bad download or [potentially bad source media](http://amanita-design.net/forum/index.php/topic,4367.0.html).

I would attempt to re-download the `.dmg`, optionally from a mirror if possible. If that fails, contact Amantia Design and report the problem. Worst case scenario is that they should be able to refund you and you can try getting the game via another method (the App Store, or Steam perhaps).